# Why the value of the progress bar stay the same?When reading the RegistryKey

Tags: multithreading, progress-bar, registrykey

Code in the main form:

```
private delegate bool IncreaseProbarHandler(int nIncVal);   //Declare a delegate to increase the progress bar value.
    private IncreaseProbarHandler _IncHanler = null;
    private List<Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey> _RKeys = new List<Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey>(); //Store the RegistryKey.
    public MainForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        new Thread(ProThread).Start();
        RecursiveRegedit(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser);
        //RecursiveRegedit(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine);
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
    }
    //Recursive scan the registry.
    void RecursiveRegedit(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regBoot) {
        if(regBoot == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Null Item!");
        string[] vals = regBoot.GetValueNames();
        foreach(var v in vals) {
            if(regBoot.GetValue(v) != null) {
                string s = regBoot.GetValue(v).ToString();
                if(s.StartsWith("C:", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    _RKeys.Add(regBoot);    //Add to 'List'.
            }
        }
        if(regBoot.SubKeyCount <= 0)    //Exit.
            return;
        else {  //Recursive.
            string[] subs = regBoot.GetSubKeyNames();
            foreach(string s in subs) {
                try {//Try...catch the not accessible notes exception.
                    RecursiveRegedit(regBoot.OpenSubKey(s, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights.FullControl));
                }
                catch {
                }
            }
        }
        regBoot.Close();    //Close.
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Show Progress bar form.
    /// </summary>
    void ShowProbar() {
        ProgressBarForm proForm = new ProgressBarForm();
        _IncHanler = new IncreaseProbarHandler(proForm.IncreaseProbarVal);
        proForm.Show();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Sub Thread to perform the progress bar.
    /// </summary>
    void ProThread() {
        MethodInvoker mInvoker = new MethodInvoker(ShowProbar);
        this.BeginInvoke(mInvoker);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        bool incResult = false; //The status each time when trying to increase the progress bar value.
        do {
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            incResult = (bool)this.Invoke(this._IncHanler, new object[] { 2 });
        } while(incResult);
    }
```

Code in the Progress bar form:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Increase the value of the progress bar.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="incVal">The value to increase.</param>
    /// <returns>True if increase successful,otherwise false.</returns>
    public bool IncreaseProbarVal(int incVal) {
        if(incVal <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Increase value can't the a negative.");
        if(proBar.Value + incVal < proBar.Maximum) {
            proBar.Value += incVal;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            proBar.Value = proBar.Maximum;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Description:
I read the registry key value in the main form recursively using try catch statement.I started a new thread to perform the progress bar form.
The current issue is that,the progress bar form is not appear when running the app.It shows when the main form done(But the value of the progrss bar stay the same,or say not increase).
Some one said that whether I could sure the main jop is not block and has free time to perform the progress bar.I confuse about this and I just don't use the state 'block' or something else.So that must be some other question,or could you launch me someting and have some ideal? 
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

What a mess...a lot of un-necessary threading and Invoke()ing.  =\

"The current issue is that,the progress bar form is not appear when running the app.It shows when the main form done"

Your call to RecursiveRegedit() is running on the main thread UI...thus nothing can be updated until the recursive calls are complete.

You need to run RecursiveRegedit() from another thread like you're doing with ProThread().

Comment: Thanks very much,you are right,But I have done my jop using the Background Worker.Thanks again and I get the point.